# AutoDisposeStreamProvider is not being disposed at loggin out

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, riverpod

Currently, we are using **Firebase** to implement a simple chat on our application.

We handle the application's launch and authentication with **Riverpod**.

Launching goes like as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LocalNotificationService()
        .handleApplicationWasLaunchedFromNotification(_onSelectNotification);
    LocalNotificationService().setOnSelectNotification(_onSelectNotification);
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotification();

    // final navigator = useProvider(navigatorProvider);
    final Settings? appSettings = useProvider(settingsNotifierProvider);
    final bool darkTheme = appSettings?.darkTheme ?? false;
    final LauncherState launcherState = useProvider(launcherProvider);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
      <SystemUiOverlay>[SystemUiOverlay.bottom],
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Thesis Cancer',
      theme: darkTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => launcherState.when(
          loading: () => SplashScreen(),
          needsProfile: () => LoginScreen(),
          profileLoaded: () => MainScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Currently, we just enable logging out from main screen and rooms screen as follows:

```
ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                    title: const Text('Çıkış yap'),
                    onTap: () =>
                        context.read(launcherProvider.notifier).signOut(),
                  ),
```

Where `signOut` does:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    tokenController.state = '';
    userController.state = User.empty;
    await dataStore.removeUserProfile();
    _auth.signOut();
    state = const LauncherState.needsProfile();
  }
```

The problem is, every time we goes to the `RoomsPage` and we do logout from it or from the main page (coming back from rooms), we get the same problem with **firebase**:
[image]
`The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.`.
Of course, `signout` closes the **Firebase**, thence **Firebase** throws this error; but, it is supposed after coming out from the **RoomsScreen** (it happens even when go back to the main screen), this widget is disposed therefore the connection should be closed, disposed, but it seems it is still on memory.

The **RoomPage** screen is as follows:

```
class RoomsPage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AsyncValue<List<fc_types.Room>> rooms =
        useProvider(roomsListProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Header(
        pageTitle: "Uzmanlar",
        leading: const BackButton(),
      ),
      endDrawer: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 275),
        child: SideMenu(),
      ),
      body: rooms.when(
        data: (List<fc_types.Room> rooms) {
          if (rooms.isEmpty) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 200,
              ),
              child: const Text('No rooms'),
            );
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: rooms.length,
            itemBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              int index,
            ) {
              final fc_types.Room room = rooms[index];

              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => pushToPage(
                  context,
                  ChatPage(
                    room: room,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16,
                    vertical: 8,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 40,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 16,
                        ),
                        width: 40,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Image.network(room.imageUrl ?? ''),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(room.name ?? 'Room'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        loading: () => const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
        error: (Object error, StackTrace? stack) => ErrorScreen(
          message: error.toString(),
          actionLabel: 'Home',
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the provider is  simple:

```
final AutoDisposeStreamProvider<List<fc_types.Room>> roomsListProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<fc_types.Room>>(
  (_) async* {
    final Stream<List<fc_types.Room>> rooms = FirebaseChatCore.instance.rooms();
    await for (final List<fc_types.Room> value in rooms) {
      yield value;
    }
  },
  name: "List Rooms Provider",
);
```

I suppose the **AutoDispose** constructor makes this provider auto disposed when the widget is removed, so, it should close the connection with **Firebase** (as de documentation says).

WHat's the problem here?

What am i missing?

Should i open an issue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StreamProvider-class.html), the example is using a `Stream` based on a `StreamController`

```dart
final messageProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<String>((ref) async* {
  // Open the connection
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  // Close the connection when the stream is destroyed
  ref.onDispose(() => channel.sink.close());

  // Parse the value received and emit a Message instance
  await for (final value in channel.stream) {
    yield value.toString();
  }
});
```

In your case, your method is returning a `Stream`. This changes the game rules. Just return the `Stream`.

```dart
final AutoDisposeStreamProvider<List<fc_types.Room>> roomsListProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<fc_types.Room>>(
  (_) => FirebaseChatCore.instance.rooms(),
  name: "List Rooms Provider",
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
As you cannot cancel a Stream directly, you could just forward the `FirebaseCore.instance.rooms()` and let the provider do the cleanup:

```
final AutoDisposeStreamProvider<List<fc_types.Room>> roomsListProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<fc_types.Room>>(
  (_) => FirebaseChatCore.instance.rooms(),
  name: "List Rooms Provider",
);
```

**Previous Answer:**

`autoDispose` only closes the provided Stream itself (the one you create by using `async*`), but you will still need too close the Firebase stream yourself.

You can use `onDispose()` as shown in the [Riverpod documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose/#example-cancelling-http-requests-when-no-longer-used)

```
  ref.onDispose(() => rooms.close());
```

Comment: The method 'close' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.

Comment: It is suposed to be what i did, also i followed the documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StreamProvider-class.html

Comment: And also, the types there are wrong:
`final StreamProvider<List<fc_types.Room>> roomsProvider =
    StreamProvider<List<fc_types.Room>>(
  (_) => FirebaseChatCore.instance.rooms(),
);`